# SDL2 retina display macbook blurry window

Tags: macos, window, retina-display, sdl-2, hdpi

I'm trying to create a window with SDL v2.0.3 using Xcode 6 with my 2012 retina display Macbook Pro like this:

```
gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 2880, 1800, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN |SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
```

The window appears way bigger than the screen and the x/min/max icons are blurry. Am I doing something wrong? When I do:

```
    int w;
    int h;
    SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize(gWindow, &w, &h);
```

I get 2880, 1880.

Answer (score 1):

Realized I just need to set High Resolution Capable to yes in the Info.plist

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem, but I don't understand which Info.plist file are you editing? I just build my executable with clang and run it, don't have any .plist file.